# Why 7z compression speed and CPU usage are low

Tags: compression, 7-zip

On such system:

[image]

To compress with 7Zip I use such setting:

[image]

The compression looks like:

[image]

[image]

I even change compression level to `0 - no compression` and change destination disc to separate physical SSD drive, but still compression speed is about 40 MB/s and CPU usage is low.

**QUESTION:** Why CPU usage and thus compression speed are so low?
Is this related to HDD speed on source drive C: ?

**Remarks:**

- Source data to compress, are located on C:
- Destination is set to E:
- Both drives are separate physcal drive
- C: is HDD
- E: is SSD

Comment: this is clearly IO bound.  also most DB backups are going to be compressed already, and its likely unable to compress them to any significant degree.

Comment: SQL Server BAK files compress very well, this is visible in the screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

By checking without compression you already confirmed the reason: you're not limited by CPU power but rather by IOPS. If you truly do have a hard disk (spinning rust), this is speed (40+ MB/s reading + 40 MB/s writing + seeking) is acceptable. In your screenshot, the destination is *not* on your SSD. Your hard drive may also be busy otherwise with regular operations.

It appears Windows Server does not show the hard drive in Task Manager but maybe you can see it in Resource Monitor and confirm that it is in fact ~100% busy.